# What is the right way to move the mouse in a game?

Tags: java, mouse

I want to program a bot for minecraft that automatically collects items. But I have a problem to move the mouse in the game. The movement acts strange... it is jumping around at the x and y coordination even if I only add 1 to the y coordinate. The movment acts like this in every 3D game not only in minecraft.

For the movement I use the [integreated robot class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html).

Here is the snipped I use for the mouse movement:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        Robot bot = new Robot();

        Point mouseposition = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
        int x = mouseposition.x;
        int y = mouseposition.y;

        //used to switch to the game window
        bot.delay(5000);

        y += 1;

        bot.mouseMove(x, y);

    } catch (AWTException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

What I was expecting with this code was, that the course just move one pixel down. The cursor is moving fine if I am on the desktop!

**System:**

> - os: Windows 8.1
> - arch: amd64
> - javaversion: 1.7.0_67
> - ide: eclipse luna

Comment: What does bot.mouseMove(x, y) do?  Do you have the code for this?

Comment: @david99world This is in the integrated [robot class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) for java. It should move the mouse to the x and y coordination of the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're capturing the mouse location before you switch to the game window, so when you add 1 to the y coordinate, you're actually adding 1 to where the mouse was *before* you moved it to switch to the game window. Put the delay before the `Point mouseposition = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();` line instead.

Comment: *facepalm* Thank you very much... yes your right I got the coords before I was in the game! Dident find the mistake